# Split array of dates into ranges

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, date, split

I want to split this array of objects. This is just a part of the whole array which contains bookings for the next two years.

```
[ { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-01T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-02T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-03T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-04T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-05T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-06T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-27T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-28T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-29T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-30T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-31T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-01T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-02T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-03T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-04T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-05T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-06T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-07T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-08T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-09T23:00:00.000Z } ]
```

into arrays grouped by consecutive dates, like that:

```
[ [ { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-01T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-02T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-03T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-04T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-05T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-06T23:00:00.000Z } ],
  [ { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-27T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-28T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-29T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-30T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-01-31T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-01T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-02T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-03T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-04T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-05T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-06T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-07T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-08T23:00:00.000Z },
  { state: 'BOOKED', date: 2017-02-09T23:00:00.000Z } ] ]
```

I'm going crazy right now. Update:

What I tried so far:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var moment = require('moment');

var bookings = [
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-01-01T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-01-02T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-01-03T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-01-04T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-01-05T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-01-06T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-01-27T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-01-28T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-01-29T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-01-30T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-01-31T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-01T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-02T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-03T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-04T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-05T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-06T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-07T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-08T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-09T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-18T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-19T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-20T23:00:00.000Z')},
    {state: 'BOOKED', date: moment('2017-02-21T23:00:00.000Z')}
];

var ranges = {};
var range = 1;

_.each(bookings, function (booking, idx) {
    var next = idx + 1;

    if (!ranges[range]) {
        ranges[range] = [];
    }

    if (!bookings[next]) {
        return;
    }

    if (booking.date.clone().add(1, 'day').isSame(bookings[next].date)) {
        ranges[range].push(booking);
    } else {
        range++;
    }
});
```

Which kind of works, BUT only if the objects inside the array are in the correct order.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question does not shows any sign of effort.

Comment: I really can't understand what are you trying to do

Comment: Show us your attempts so far, your code should at least contain a for loop or something equivalent.

Comment: @Mr.Bruno OP wants to group consecutive dates. Thing is, I have already solved it. Just wondering should answer it or not

Comment: @Milzer if you show us your code that would show us that you have tried something and we could help you with more that just answering problem

Comment: Why don't you give us the `forEach` code snippet ? We just need to see you have done some reasonable effort, rather than using SO as a coding service. I have working code right here in my console, will post it as soon as you post your best attempt so far.

Comment: @Jaco then its a race... :-p

Comment: @Jaco I'm not using SO as a coding service ;) I'm only using it when the frustration is high and the window is already opened for me to jump out...

Comment: @Milzer Just remember the importance of code/effort in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` function to loop over data and match current and next value.

#### Idea

- Create a temp variable to hold previous value and a temp array to hold current group.
- Loop over data and for each iteration, check current value to the temp variable's value.
- If the difference is 1, then push it in a temp array. Reset temp array and push current element in it.
- If not and temp array has values, push temp array in final array.

#### Sample Code

```js
var data=[{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-01-01T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-01-02T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-01-03T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-01-04T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-01-05T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-01-06T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-01-27T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-01-28T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-01-29T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-01-30T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-01-31T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-02-01T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-02-02T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-02-03T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-02-04T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-02-05T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-02-06T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-02-07T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-02-08T23:00:00.000Z"},{state:"BOOKED",date:"2017-02-09T23:00:00.000Z"}];
  
var result = [];
var lastDate = null;
data.reduce(function(p, c, i, a){
 var date = new Date(c.date);
  if (!(lastDate === null || getDiffInDays(lastDate, date) === 1)){
   result.push(p);
    p=[];
  }
  p.push(c)
  if(i === a.length - 1 && p.length > 0){
   result.push(p);
  }
  lastDate = date;
  return p;
},[])

console.log(result)

function getDiffInDays(d1, d2){
 if(d1 && d2){
   var milliSecInDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return parseInt((+d2 - +d1)/milliSecInDay);
  }
}
```